# SwiftUI How to enable buttons on the views which have gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to put buttons on the view which has DragGesture by ZStack. But when I put buttons on the view, it doesn't work.

```swift
    struct TmpView5: View {

    @State var position: CGSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 250)

    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
        .onChanged{ value in
            self.position = CGSize(
                width: value.startLocation.x
                    + value.translation.width,
                height: value.startLocation.y
                    + value.translation.height
            )
        }
        .onEnded{ value in
            self.position = CGSize(
                width: value.startLocation.x
                    + value.translation.width,
                height: value.startLocation.y
                    + value.translation.height
            )
        }
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
            
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .position(x: position.width, y: position.height)
                    .gesture(drag)
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("taped!!!")
                    }){
                        Image(systemName:"photo.on.rectangle")
                    }.padding(.trailing)
                    
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("taped!!!")
                    }){
                        Image(systemName:"a")
                            .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove gesture(drag), I can tap buttons. Is it possible to add gesture on the Rectangle and enable buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine, just buttons too close to each other and have too small internal area, so add more internal padding for each as shown below (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
HStack {
    Button(action: {
        print("taped!!!")
    }){
        Image(systemName:"photo.on.rectangle").padding()    // << here !!
    }
    
    Button(action: {
        print("taped!!!")
    }){
        Image(systemName:"a").padding()     // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot. 
It works, but why does it worked fine when I just removed the gesture? Does gesture affect the buttons padding?

Comment: When there are two gestures it cannot resolve correctly conflict between them due to small tappable area of buttons, but when you remove one gesture, there is no alternate and buttons work.

Comment: But sorry actually I posted one more question on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168981/swiftui-boundingrect-doesnt-work-fine-by-uiviewrepresentable-updateuiview
If you check this later, I'm really appreciate it !